# Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute' expected 2 arguments, got 1

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to get the attribute value of image src, failed with message

> Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute' expected 2
>   arguments, got 1.

```
${src}=    Get Element Attribute     xpath=${locator}@src
```

Expected result is to get image src attribute value.
Actual result is keyword is getting failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you are trying to pass the attribute is deprecated based on the documentation:

> Passing attribute name as part of the locator is deprecated since Selenium2Library 3.0. The explicit attribute argument should be used instead.

Documentation for [Get Element Attribute](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) Keyword

Therefore you will need to pass in locator and attribute name to `Get Element Attribute` as below:

```
${src}=    Get Element Attribute    xpath=${locator}    src
```